# Angular: Two outlets both without names still work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I cannot seem to figure out how this is working, I have an app with two `router-outlet` tags. Neither of the tags have a `name` associated with them, so how are the components displayed in the correct outlet?

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'settings',
        component: SettingsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then in the `AppComponent` template there is this, which shows the `LoginComponent` and the `HomeComponent`.

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Then in the `HomeComponent` template there is this, which shows the `SettingsComponent` or `ProfileComponent`.

```html
<ul class="nav"></ul>
<div class="content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

From what I have read, you need to have a named outlet and tell the route which outlet to render to. Why do I not need one here? This still works. What is happening? I cannot find a reasoning for this on Google other than to use a route with a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nested primary router outlets work fine and are very commonly used, in fact, it's the ONLY way parent / child routes can work.

With nested outlets, the router figures out what to render pretty intuitively, based on the parent / child structure of your route config.

You only need named outlets if they are siblings.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, I had a hard time finding documentation on that.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes .. not super explicit but covers it somewhat

Comment: my opinion on named outlets, if you're new to angular, they're a headache and more trouble than they're worth. It was an interesting idea but they've always caused more problems than they've solved when I've tried to use them and I've never worked on an app that used them effectively in the dozens of angular apps I've worked on.